# Google Drive search API sending partial result

Tags: google-drive-api

I have 2 files in my drive with following names
1. file test 1
2. file_test_1

When I search using "test" below query is sent to google.

```
title contains 'test'
```

But drive api returns only "file test 1" and not "file_test_1".

Is this expected? From docs it says search will be based on prefix in file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will search for matching **words**.

So "file test 1" contains the three words "file", "test" and "1" and so matches. "file_test_1" contains a single word "file_test_1" and so doesn't match.